# Can I read The Treatise of the Dragons?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

Is there anything wrong with studying the Kabbalistic writings of Natan of Gaza (Shabatai Tzvi's navi) such as his Treatise on the Dragons? It seems to be a compilation of many explanations found in other Lurianic works? Is there anything in there that would be off-limits for an Orthodox Jew?

Comment: This seems about as valuable as reading Harry Potter's books on dragons, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA. Reading it makes it pretty clear how fungible the Lurianic concepts are and how simple it is to take them in any direction needed or wanted.  I believe that that is much more important than Harry Potter.

Answer (score 4):

Orthodox Judaism would hold Natan of Gaza, as we know him, to be an apikorus who has thrown off the yolk of the mitzvos; and/or tried to alter the Torah and its teachings. (This applies to Sabbatai Tzvi as well, who also converted to Islam after proclaiming himself the messiah in 1648 or so)

A sefer Torah written by an apikorus should be burnt. (Yoreh Deah 281:1; see Sanhedrin 113a)

This is true even if the Torah is letter perfect.

How much more so, should one avoid a book like derush hataninim (Treatise on the Dragons).

From what I understand, he advocates in that work that the "old" Jewish laws no longer apply. This is obviously against the very core of Orthodox Judaism.

In particular, the OP describes this book as compared with "other Lurianic works". This is a bad description. Treatise of Dragons is not a Lurianic (Arizal's) work at all. The fact that Natan of Gaza studied Lurianic Kabbalah in his youth does not make his book comparable to R' Issac Luria's works. Rather it is a book written by an apikorus.

The Gemara in Chagigah (14) does discuss a case where R' Meir chose to learn Torah from his Rebbe Elisha ben Avuyah, who had gone off the path of Judaism. The Gemara says that usually one may not learn Torah from an evil person. However, R' Meir, according to one opinion, was allowed to do so because he was able to sift the good from the bad teachings.

However, in the case of Natan of Gaza, there is no reason to pursue his possible "good teachings" (if there are any) because you have so much real Lurianic Kabbalah available now with real teachers who are kosher.

Furthermore, Elisha ben Avuyah seemed to be acting out of hurt feelings and lack of willpower to change his own deeds. Natan of Gaza is trying to get Jews to throw off the Torah's commandments. Therefore, he is much more dangerous and his teachings would seem, therefore, to have no value at all.

Comment: In general, the Sabbatæans were highly influenced by Lurianic Kabbalah, as such, referring to Natan Ghazati as a Lurianic kabbalist is not incorrect.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Christianity was influenced by Judaism, yet I wouldn't call a priest a "Torah Scholar".

Comment: I'm not sure if you are referring to Nathan of Gaza before Shabatai's apostasy or after. Much of the Treatise was written before the apostasy and I don't think that there was too much bad in his thinking at that point - besides truly believing that Shabatai was Messiah. But that shouldn't disqualify his Torah writings.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I've met some in my time who had a fairly good knowledge of meforshim.

Comment: @MarkA., Sabbatai Sbi's followers created a new religion alongside him, which was more of a neo-Christianity than it was Judaism. In fact, per Graetz, he followed suppercessionist theology to a great degree, and his followers also coined the anthem of יחי אדוננו וכי׳

Comment: @MarkA. caring for the rights of the "underdog", may seem very noble. One seeking truth however, doesn't care about the "underdog"; or being "fair" to all men etc. One who seeks truth, cares about finding the truth. Jewish thought neither supports the popular opinion just because its popular; nor do we support the minority opinion just because the minority deserves a fair hearing. Jews tend to simply seek truth. :)

Comment: @MarkA. the "Treatise" was written in 1666. Almost the entire year saw S. Tzvi imprisoned and forced to convert to Islam. Belief that someone is Messiah is not in and of itself a problem. The problem is what he wrote about Theology. :) Would you like to produce something written by Natan that you really like (from the Treatise) so we can see what you mean? Would you like to give us an example of something that appears in "other Lurianic works" that you found to be spot on similar to Natan's writings?

Comment: @DavidKenner. The space alloted is too short to give specific examples but I quote Gershom Scholem - "Prima facie the pattern of thought of the Treatise is Lurianic; it contains no obvious heresies and most of its statements can be referred back to the classical Lurianic texts." Almost all Lurianic texts can, in some ways, appear to be strange if not heretical. That's why I ask if it is permissible to read it. Why is it different than the works of ibn Tabul, Shlomo Molcho,  Shimshon ben Pesach, or Yisroel Sarug? I ask from ignorance and not with an ax to grind.

Comment: @MarkA. You are quoting the middle of a paragraph from page 298 of "Sabbatai Sevi the Mystical Messiah" by G. Scholem. The beginning of the  same paragraph states: "Nathan's tract (Treatise of Dragons) presents the transition from Lurianic Kabbalism to a completely new and original type of speculation." Later in the paragraph he mentions "Prima facie" which is a scholarly term meaning: "At first glance".  It means his words sound like Lurianic Kabbalah on the surface. After an in depth read, it becomes a new doctrine.

Comment: @MarkA. Kabbalah in any case needs a teacher. It also needs a dedicated student who knows how to learn the basics of Torah first. Natan's Treatise tells people that ignoring Jewish law and even committing sin is part of the transformation of kelippah which is needed for bringing the final messiah. This is not Lurianic, and obviously heretical.